# How to disable a modified tclsh interpreter interactive mode?

Tags: tcl, interpreter, interactive-mode, tclsh

Run `tclsh` command without any tcl file, the interpreter will go into interactive mode.

Can I simply disable this feature by modifying the tclsh source code ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you would want to bother doing this, given that supplying *any* script file will turn off interactive mode. The script you supply will have full access to the additional arguments passed in (a list in the global `argv` variable) and the standard IO channels (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`). It can `exit` when it is done. Literally anything you want can be done at that point; you've just got to write a script to do it.

If you're including Tcl in your own program, the behaviour of `tclsh` is implemented in the C function `Tcl_Main`. If you never call that — instead just using `Tcl_FindExecutable`, `Tcl_CreateInterp` and `Tcl_Eval`/`Tcl_EvalFile` — then you never get any of that interactive behaviour. While theoretically you could modify the Tcl source itself to do what you want — it's all open source — why would you bother when you could just *not call that code* in the first place?